# External sharing is disabled for https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, external-sharing

I am trying to create a new web-part using the SharePoint Framework.

After doing gulp serve, If I go to the page `https://your-sharepoint-tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/workbench.aspx`, I am seeing an error page instead of workbench:

[image]

On SharePoint admin center I have checked that anyone with link property is set.

Any idea to tackle this issue?

Comment: Try to open the workbench URL from your developer site or any other team site. URL format like: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/workbench.aspx`. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first enable external sharing of the SharePoint Online site and then try to run gulp serve.

External sharing can be enabled using -

1. SharePoint Admin Center
2. Powershell

Refer [this](https://helpcenter.elearningforce.com/hc/en-us/articles/202706662-How-to-configure-external-sharing-in-SharePoint-Online) article for details.

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, it seems that it is the SharePoint admin center you are trying to share.

I don't think `https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com` is a site opeing for external sharing. Consider using another site instead: `https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx`